# Effect of assigning an empty initializer list to an existing vector or map?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have 2 containers, `a std::vector` and a `std::map`:

```
vector<int> my_vector;
map<string,int> my_map;
my_vector.push_back(3);

// elaboration of my_vector;
...

my_map["Hello"] = 1;

// elaboration of my_map
...
```

Later I do:

```
my_map = {};
my_vector = {};
```

This should make the 2 containers 2 empty containers, right? Furthermore, what happens to the memory previously pointed to from `my_map` and `my_vector`?

(I'm on C++11)

Comment: This is a good question.  What people should be asking here is whether the initializer list assignment calls the `operator=` method or the constructor which constructs from another vector since construction from an `initializer_list` for a vector is not `explicit`, or does it construct a new vector entirely and then call the move assignment operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes both assignments cause the vector and the map to be emptied.  Both the assignments are linear in the size of the vector and the map because both require every single element in the container to be destroyed before assignment, and that requires an O(n) traversal.  The vector reuses memory (https://wandbox.org/permlink/eIJEcEqERC2ybAjU) I think whether or not the map reuses memory is implementation defined (or at least I was not able to make out from the documentation)

As for the tricky part (in my opinion), which assignment operator is called here?  Is it the assignment operator from an initializer list or the move assignment operator for the vector and the map (since `{}` is implicitly convertible to an instance of either).  I found this quote from cppreference here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_direct_assignment

> Note that, if a non-template assignment operator from some non-class type is available, it is preferred over the copy/move assignment in E1 = {} because {} to non-class is an identity conversion, which outranks the user-defined conversion from {} to a class type.

So if there is a non template assignment operator, which `std::vector` does have. That is preferred over the assignment operator from a templated `std::intializer_list` assignment operator.  You just have to inspect the interface to see what is going on.  You can see the same here

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class Something {
public:
    Something() {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    template <typename U>
    Something(std::initializer_list<U>) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    Something& operator=(const Something&) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    Something& operator=(Something&&) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    Something(const Something&) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    Something(Something&&) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    template <typename U>
    Something& operator=(std::initializer_list<U>) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    // to silence unused variable warning
    int get_something() {
        return this->something;
    }
private:
    int something{1};
};

int main() {
    auto something = Something{};
    something = {};
    something = {1, 2, 3};
}
```

The output for this is

```
Something::Something()
Something::Something()
Something &Something::operator=(Something &&)
Something &Something::operator=(std::initializer_list<U>) [U = int]
```

Note that the above situation is not what happens for `std::vector` because its `initializer_list` assignment operator is not a template, so that is called.

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff4ed5bc1a70f789) shows the opposite of your example and more closely matches the situation with `std::vector`.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Strange.  Which compiler does that use?  https://wandbox.org/permlink/BL9AD6yPaZLaoSIH this uses the latest gcc version and `-std=c++1z` How does it more closely match the situation with `std::vector`?

Comment: Coliru [uses GCC 7.1.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad421967d8271db7) by default currently.  My example more closely matches `std::vector` because `std::vector`'s `std::initializer_list` assignment operator is not a template.

Comment: @MilesBudnek ah there was a difference in the example you posted.  I have updated my answer to be clearer, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Both operators copy the values from the initializer list into your container, as referenced below. Since your initializer lists are empty, your collections will be empty after copy-assignment.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator=/

Your old map and vector are destructed by their copy assign operators. "The elements stored in the container before the call are either assigned to or destroyed", as referenced in the comments to this post.

Comment: "Presumably" -- well I surely hope so ;)

Comment: Didn't want to dig through the STL documentation, but if that wasn't the case, there would be bigger problems than one incorrect answer on stack overflow.

Comment: "The elements stored in the container before the call are either assigned to or destroyed"  - the link specified in the answer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator=/  the link